# readdir taking a LONG time on mounted cifs dir

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cifs

I'm running the following code:

```
void EnumerateFolder(std::string folder)
{ 
    DIR* directory;
    struct dirent* entry;

    directory = opendir(folder.c_str());
    if(directory != NULL)
    {
        while((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << entry->d_name;
        }
    }
}
```

When it gets to a mounted CIFS folder that I have readdir() sometimes
takes **15 minutes** to return. Anyone care to enlighten me as to what is happenening
and how I can achieve a friendlier experience?
This happens every time I run the code and the computer with the shared folder
is offline. It also happens arbitrarily(as far as I can tell), perhaps when the computer
with the shared folders harddrive is "idle".

How is the folder mounted you say?

```
cat /etc/fstab
//192.168.0.6/MyShare /home/MyUser/MountedShare cifs guest 0 0
```

192.168.0.6 is running Windows 8, if that matters.
Thanks!

Comment: What result would you prefer? Would you like it to fail fast?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Preferably some sort of indication that it might take a long time, but fast failure with an error code would do. Also curious why it's 15 minutes, it succeeds after that time, mind you, but I really don't see why it takes THAT long?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Note that it also takes 15 minutes to fail if 192.168.0.6 is not on the network, in which case I think it's reasonable to assume that it would fail (pretty darn fast as well). :-)

Answer (score 1):

15 seconds is the standard [CIFS Send2 timeout](http://markmail.org/thread/vxxoicoo43ukz47v). If you want it to fail faster, you can put a `timeo` option on the mount options. Specify the timeout in tenths of a second.

The filesystem doesn't really know *why* the application wants to read the file. Fast timeouts could break long-running processes if they were, for example, faulting in pages of executable code. So generally speaking, network filesystems try to mimic the semantics of local filesystems which is to wait for as long as needed for the underlying storage to respond.

Comment: I think you misread, it takes 15 _minutes_, not seconds. That's why I'm puzzled. :-) Thanks a lot for the link though, interesting stuff I didn't know!